# Increase Sitecore.ListManagement.Operations.UpdateListOperationsAgent agent run interval

Tags: list-manager

Using sitecore 9.2 in azure, I am seeing in the logs for all of the environments entries related to the agent `Sitecore.ListManagement.Operations.UpdateListOperationsAgent` which in config by default is set to run every 10 seconds:

```
12:26:31.743 PM Job ended: Sitecore.ListManagement.Operations.UpdateListOperationsAgent (units processed: ) 
12:26:31.743 PM Job started: Sitecore.ListManagement.Operations.UpdateListOperationsAgent   
12:26:21.730 PM Job started: Sitecore.ListManagement.Operations.UpdateListOperationsAgent   
12:26:21.730 PM Job ended: Sitecore.ListManagement.Operations.UpdateListOperationsAgent (units processed: ) 
12:26:11.718 PM Job started: Sitecore.ListManagement.Operations.UpdateListOperationsAgent   
12:26:11.718 PM Job ended: Sitecore.ListManagement.Operations.UpdateListOperationsAgent (units processed: ) 
12:26:01.699 PM Job started: Sitecore.ListManagement.Operations.UpdateListOperationsAgent   
12:26:01.699 PM Job ended: Sitecore.ListManagement.Operations.UpdateListOperationsAgent (units processed: )

<scheduling>
  <agent type="Sitecore.ListManagement.Operations.UpdateListOperationsAgent, Sitecore.ListManagement" method="Run" interval="00:00:10" resolve="true" />
</scheduling>
```

I saw various posts that were mentioning that increasing this agent to run at 30 min will speed up the local environment. I am trying to find out if the agent can affect the performance of the website in any way and if the interval should be increased in higher environments aswell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this UpdateListOperation influence your server performance.

Please have a look if you have children under the item: /sitecore/system/List Manager/ListOperations .

On the agent you have next method which run :

```
public void Run()
    {
      foreach (ListOperation operation in this._listOperationRepository.GetOperations())
      {
        if (operation.Status == OperationStatus.Indexing)
        {
          BaseJobManager jobManager = this._jobManager;
          Guid id = operation.Id;
          string jobName = id.ToString();
          if (jobManager.GetJob(jobName) == null)
          {
            id = operation.Id;
            this._jobManager.Start((BaseJobOptions) new DefaultJobOptions(id.ToString(), operation.OperationType, Context.GetSiteName(), (object) this, "CheckIndexing", new object[1]
            {
              (object) operation
            }));
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

In your case **_listOperationRepository.GetOperations()** should return empty results so it takes few miliseconds to finish the Agent.
Please have a look on other things which can influence performance like DTU of the databases, sizes of app services or the custom code.

Answer (score 0):

As you wrote in your question, there are plenty of article suggesting that in your `DEV` environment, you should increase the value of interval for `UpdateListOperationsAgent`.

I only remember 1 article mentioning that change for higher environments in Azure: https://www.krusicbruno.com/optimizing-sitecore-performance-on-azure-paas-part-1/

So is this safe to increase that value in higher environments? You won't break anything but all of your list-related operations will be executed with lower frequency. I would not worry if that's 30 seconds instead of 10 seconds, 1 minute maybe. But definitely I would not change it to 30 or 60 minutes, like it's suggested in some blog posts for `DEV` environment.

Will it make any improvement when it comes to performance? In my opinion not really. All the operations will be updated anyway, just a bit later than usual.